# No source control option in SQL Server 2017 Management Studio

Tags: tfs, version-control, sql-server-2017

[image: no src control]

Screenshot above is from my SSMS 2017.

I want begin to use tfs on SQL server and I googled how to use it and apparently there should be an option for source control in tools-->option but there is no option for source control. How can I fix it?

I have VS 2017 and 2015 and I'm using tfs on vs 2017 right now. No problem there.
I have team foundation server 2018 installed too.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the packages which source control needed are not as part of SSMS.

However you can try to enable the Visual Studio packages manually. See [Source Control in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/) for details.

> **To enable TFS integration in SSMS, follow these steps:**
>
> 1) Close SSMS if it is running.
>
> 2) Install Visual Studio 2015 on your SSMS machine. If you don’t
>   already have Visual Studio, Community Edition will work fine. This is
>   a large download but you can save some space by unselecting all
>   languages during the Visual Studio install if your only purpose is to
>   enable Source Control in SSMS.
>
> 3) Edit the ssms.pkgundef file found at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef.
>
> At the top of this file there are a series of packages grouped
>   together related to TFS Source Control features. These packages must
>   be removed from the pkgundef file. This can be done by either deleting
>   the section or commenting out each line using ‘//’. Here is an example
>   of what the section should look like if commented out:// TFS SCC
>   Configuration entries. The TFS entries block Team Explorer from
>   loading.
>
> ```
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Lab
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{17c5d08a-602c-4dfb-82b5-8e0f7f50c9d7}]
> // GitHub Package
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc}]
> // Team Foundation Server Provider Package
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{5BF14E63-E267-4787-B20B-B814FD043B38}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPackage
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{6238f138-0c0c-49ec-b24b-215ee59d84f0}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.BuildPackage
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{739f34b3-9ba6-4356-9178-ac3ea81bdf47}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{ca39e596-31ed-4b34-aa36-5f0240457a7e}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{b80b010d-188c-4b19-b483-6c20d52071ae}]
> // Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.SccProviderPackage
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{7fe30a77-37f9-4cf2-83dd-96b207028e1b}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.SccPcwPluginPackage
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{1b4f495a-280a-3ba4-8db0-9c9b735e98ce}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}]
> // Visual SourceSafe Provider Package
> //[$RootKey$\Packages\{AA8EB8CD-7A51-11D0-92C3-00A0C9138C45}]
> // Visual SourceSafe Provider Stub Package
>   [$RootKey$\Packages\{53544C4D-B03D-4209-A7D0-D9DD13A4019B}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Initialization.InitializationPackage
>   [$RootKey$\Packages\{75DF55D4-EC28-47FC-88AC-BE56203C9012}]
> // Team Foundation Server Provider Stub Package
>   [$RootKey$\Packages\{D79B7E0A-F994-4D4D-8FAE-CAE147279E21}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SccDisplayInformationPackage
>   [$RootKey$\Packages\{D7BB9305-5804-4F92-9CFE-119F4CB0563B}]
> // Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Lab.LabPcwPluginPackage
>    [$RootKey$\Packages\{e0910062-da1f-411c-b152-a3fc6392ee1f}]
>    [$RootKey$\ToolsOptionsPages\Source Control]
>    [$RootKey$\AutoLoadPackages\{11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8}]
> // TFS SCC Configuration entries.
> ```
>
> Once completed, start SSMS and the “Team” menu should be visible in
>   the SSMS menu bar. This menu and related features are the standard
>   Visual Studio functionality. This enables connections to TFS servers
>   or Git servers.

Comment: (for SSMS 2017 the path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.pkgundef)

Comment: @DarthTommy: Yes, this works with SSMS 17.9; the path is same with 140 instead of 130 == C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio